# Azure Deploy of CM + Reporting

Tags: azure, paas, deployment

I'd like to build a deployment of CM and Reporting in a single App Service.
Is the best approach to take the XP0 files and try to remove what isn't needed ?
Or try and combine The CM and Reporting from XP Scaled ?
Is there any kind of walk through for this type of customization ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot on expected load as to what the best scaling configuration is, but I will not go into that here.

To specifically answer your question, you can take the XP Scaled configuration and modify as follows:

- `infrastructure.json`: remove resource sections for the Reporting `Microsoft.Web/sites` and Reporting `Microsoft.Web/serverfarms` and any references / dependencies to those resources
- `application.json`: remove the deployment of the Reporting site and any references / dependencies. It should still be setting the reporting DB connection string on your CM.
- `Sitecore xxx (Cloud)_cm.scwdp.zip`: alter the web.config `<add key="role:define" value="ContentManagement,Reporting" />`. Or `ContentManagement,Reporting,Indexing` if on 9.2+

I would like to note though that it's possible Sitecore haven't tested this specific configuration before.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to keep them separate azure web apps, but group CM and Reporting to the same app hosting plan. This way you don't have to regenerate the sitecore provided packages.

More information on Azure App Hosting plans can be found here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-plan-manage

Comment: Having multiple core roles (i.e. ones that run Sitecore.Kernel) on one hosting plan is going to be tough with amount of resources on anything but a P3V2.

Comment: Definitely. But the OP is asking how to group them into the same App Service, which in my opinion is more work.